# Предлагаю объединить метки "определения" и "определение"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки `определения` и `определение`. Мы последовательно оставляем названия меток во мн. ч., так что пусть `определения` будет главной.

Answer (score 1):

Метки объединены, синонимы созданы; спасибо за помощь!